# Is there a list of released JDK versions?

Tags: version, java

I've got a server running with JRE 7 Update 19. I tought it would be proper to install the JDK 7 as update 19 also. However, I'm struggling to find a download to that version.

Current release is Update 21, so I'm thinking if there never may have been a official Version 19. Is there some kind of list which shows all released versions of the JDK?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: In that case I guess, Version 19 has never been released. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is a list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

There is also a list of [release notes for Oracle Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html).

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia link of [Java Version History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

Answer (score 3):

Note that having a version number *never* (like  u19) released makes sense in the view of the [new version numbering Scheme announced early May 2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jdk-version-number-scheme-1918258.html):

> we are changing the frequency and way in which these releases are numbered:
>
> Limited Update releases will be numbered in multiples of 20.
>
> We intend for Critical Patch Updates (CPU) to continue to use odd numbers.
>   The numbers will be calculated by adding multiples of five to the prior Limited Update and when needed adding one to keep the resulting number odd.
>
> This is best illustrated with an example:
>
> The next Limited Update for JDK 7 will be numbered 7u40, and the next 3 CPUs after that will be numbered 7u45, 7u51, and 7u55.
>   The next release will be a Limited Update 7u60, followed by CPUs 7u65, 7u71, and 7u75.
>
> **This numbering scheme will leave several numbers between releases which will allow us to insert releases – for example security alerts or support releases, should that become necessary - without having to renumber later releases**.

Answer (score 0):

check out this webpage and it illustrates the version releases on each JDK.

> > http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-features-and-history/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the post obviously only covers major changes in Java.

Comment: And I do hope Sasi had answered that? :)